# How to mask output logging in Knife.rb file

Tags: chef-infra, knife

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "test"
client_key               "C:/Python27/Lib/site"
validation_key           "/nonexist"
chef_server_url          ""
```

I've got knife.rb file which is exposing the client key to the output and i want the logging to stop to prevent this.  Is there any way I can set this log location to NULL?

Answer (score 1):

as you can see, you are using `STDOUT` [ruby predefined global variable](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants), switching it with `File::NULL` may do the trick.

here is an untested example

```rb
log_location    File.open(File::NULL, "w")
```